# I am getting webdriver error in intelliJ IDE while using Selenium?

Tags: selenium, intellij-idea

I am using intelliJ IDE for Selenium Project. This error does not happen in Ellipse IDE. Here is a snapshot of the issue. This code works perfectly in Ellipse. I have added dependencies jar files for Selenium.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Errors are underlined with red, this is green. I think it just a spelling error indication.
Also the "error" is in a string, you cannot get a syntax or runtime error in a string.

If you get a error during running the tests please add that error and stacktrace to your question and I will try to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

These under waved warnings are spellchecking warings and intellij idea has an integrated spell checker.

Spellchecker configuration:
[image: Spell checker configuration]

You can deactivate the spell checking:
[image: deactivate spell checking]

You can save that word on a project level to your spelling directory:
[image: save word on project level]

These two options will remove the warning. Making this warning less catchy by changing the color scheme could be an other option:
[image]